# how to sort on the ReferenceField column in Admin-on-rest list view

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am sorry, if I have missed this piece in documentation. Please show me how to sort a ReferenceField column on username value rather than id in the list/datagrid view.

```
<ReferenceField label="User" source="userId" reference="users" linkType="show">
  <TextField source="username" />
</ReferenceField>
```

As in this [example](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/commands) sorting by Customer doesn't make much sense when ordered by Id.

Comment: See https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1361

Comment: We are also needing this, the sort is not working correctly as it is now

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr

Add `sortBy="username"` to the `<ReferenceField>` component.

**Note:** This solution **only works with [`react-admin`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) 2.1** and above!

### Explanation

On their [2018 July blog post](https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/07/02/react-admin-2-1.html#sort-by-reference-name-or-title) they announced:

> React-admin 2.1 now allows you to specify the name of the field to use for sorting in a `<ReferenceField>`, using the `sortBy` prop:
>
> ```js
> <ReferenceField label="User" source="userId" reference="users" sortBy="user.name">
>   <TextField source="name" />
> </ReferenceField>
> ```

They also have a [section for this in the documentation on `<List>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#specify-sort-field) with the following code example:

```js
<ReferenceField label="Post" source="id" reference="posts" sortBy="title">
  <TextField source="title" />
</ReferenceField>
```

Comment: Adding a sortBy property made to a ReferenceField column in a DataGrid made no difference to sorting for me.

I'm using the Firebase Realtime db via the [ra-data-firebase-client](https://github.com/aymendhaya/ra-data-firebase-client).  I'm guessing that this is probably a back-end limitation.

Comment: you need to configure your data adapter to pass this info in the way that your backend expects